# regex to filter whenever 4 alphabetical characters are present consecutively

Tags: javascript, regex

Whenever 4 alphabetical characters are written in a row it should not be allowed.
eg:

```
ABCD: error
ABC1: allowed
ABC1233...: allowed
```

As soon as the 4th alphabetical character is typed it should give error.
I have tried:

```
(/^[a-zA-Z]{3,}.+$/.test(value))
```

On typing abcd: it gives error, which is working fine.
abc1: it again shows error. This error is not correct. This input should be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you you want to have 3 letters and then everything else as letters?

Go for that regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}[^a-zA-Z]+$
```

If you want only number behind the letters go for that:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just search the string for `[a-zA-Z]{4,}`, if there is ANY match at all then there are four alphanumeric letters in a row in the string, if there are no matches the string is allowed.

Comment: i have tried this exp, but it shows an error when i type ABC1, 4th character can be a digit but it shouldnt be a alphabet.

Comment: @user2315252 Go to http://www.regexpal.com/ and put [a-zA-Z]{4,} and ABCD and ABC1 on separate lines as the text. ABCD will match and ABC1 will not.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Seems like your requirements are as follows:
You want to accept strings containing **only** alphanumeric characters AND **not** beginning with 4 or more consecutive letters AND **not** being empty.

In that case your regex should look like this:

```
           /^(\\d|[a-zA-Z]{1,3}(\\d|$))/
            v \_/ \___________/\_____/
            |  |        |          |
         ___|  |        |          |
 _______|_    _|___    _|_____    _|____________
|match the|  |match|  |match  |  |match either  |
|beginning|  |one  |  |1 to 3 |  |a digit or the|
|of string|  |digit|  |letters|  |end of srtring|
 ---------    -----    -------    --------------
```

This could be interpreted as:

```
Match the beginning of the string  
  followed by:  
    either: one digit
    or    : one to three letters
              followed by:
                either: one digit
                or    : the end of the string
```

Sample code:

```
var strArr = ["ABC", "ABCD", "ABC123DEFG", "ABCD1234"];
var regex = new RegExp("^(\\d|[a-zA-Z]{1,3}(\\d|$))");
for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    alert(strArr[i] + ": " + (regex.test(strArr[i]) ? "ALLOWED" : " NOT ALLOWED"));
}
```

See, also, this (*UPDATED*) **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/KMmd7/)**.

Comment: the above failed for input abc123abcd

Comment: When you say "failed" you mean it returned "not allowed" ? It is designed to do so (because there are 4 consecutive letters in 'abc123abcd'). If I misinterpreted your requirements, please elaborate :) Do you want to only prevent strings that **start** with 4 letter ?

Comment: the string should not start with 4 alphabets in a row, however any 3 alpabets followed by any number of digits and followed by any number of alpbhabets or digits are allowed
combination as below:
abc11111abbbbbbb122222: allowed
abcd233jjhk1hh: not allowed
abcd:not allwoed
ab87676jhgjhg89uijhkha allowed

i have tried if (/^([a-zA-Z]{3,}[a-zA-Z])+$/.test(value))
results:
ABCD: error. workin fine
abc2: allowed, workin fine
abc222768jhjjh87yjhjh: allwoed workin fine
abcd2:HERE IT FAILS
As soon as i enter number after 4 alphabets it doesnt show error, however it should show js error

Comment: Is a string starting with digits allowed ?

Comment: yup. just 4 alphabets in a row are nt allowed